# Pokemon GO, not able to sign in with Google account

Tags: pokemon-go

I got Pokemon GO on a new device as my other one broke, when I press Sign up with Google, it just has a Pokeball in the centre loading and nothing else. the bottom I can cancel still but I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Could you specify what device you are using? That would really help in figuring out what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the "spinning-ball-never-going-away" problem is solved by ending and restarting the app. How to do that depends on the device.  But generally...

**On iPhone:**

1. View your open apps. Double-click the Home button to see your most recently used apps.
2. Find the app to close. Swipe right or left to find the app that you want to close.
3. Swipe up to close. Swipe up on the app's preview to close the app.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201330

**On Android:**
I typically tap the double-window icon with the 2 squares, find the PokemonGo app in that Rolodex menu (it's usually on top), then tap the X.  Or, you can follow these instructions:

1. Open the Settings app.
2. Choose Apps. ...
3. Touch the Running tab to view only active or running apps. ...
4. Choose the app that's causing you distress. ...
5. Touch the Stop or Force Stop button.

http://www.dummies.com/consumer-electronics/smartphones/droid/how-to-force-close-an-app-on-an-android-phone/